# iPad - programmatically display content in DetailViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm very desperate to my problem. I do app for iPad (using UISplitViewController) and I load data from XML (it works well). Is there any possibility to view the content programmatically in DetailViewController? I still displayed in MasterViewController.

**Part of my code that I use:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self showDetailsForIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self showDetailsForIndexPath:indexPath];
}


-(void) showDetailsForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    ipaddetailViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ipaddetailViewController"];


    Slova* slova;


    if(isFiltered)
    {
        slova = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        slova = [self.slovoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    vc.slovoItem = slova;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true]; 
}
```

**This is how my problem (after I click on one of Cells):**
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can fetch content using indexpath. This is how we pass data from master to detail view controller. If possible please elaborate what actually you are looking for? Question not clear.

Comment: My problem is that my content is displayed in MasterViewContoller, but I need it to display in DetailViewController. I'm sorry, but I do not know how to describe it better.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your explanation is you want to display in detail view controller as app loads. This you can achieve by passing value to detail view controller from master view viewDidLoad method -

Try like this, hope this is what you are looking for

```
self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
[self.detailViewController setDetailItem:@"My Test"];
```